# JIRA filter, AND, OR - compound conditions

Tags: boolean, jira, jql

I can do this(1):

```
reporter = currentUser() and project = "Example" ORDER BY created DESC
```

but not this(2):

```
project = "Example" ORDER BY created DESC and reporter = currentUser()
```

JIRA complains:

```
Expecting ',' but got 'and'. (line 1, character 38)
```

Is it possible to somehow specify conditions in 2nd format (2)?

Comment: project = "Example" AND reporter = currentUser() ORDER BY created DESC